# How to use Strtok for tokenizing a Const char*?

Tags: c++, c, strtok

I have a const char* variable which may have a value like "OpenStack:OpenStack1". I want to tokenize this const char* using strtok where the delimiter(which is of a const char* type) is ":" . But the problem is strtok is of following type:
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );

Which means I can't use const char* for the first input as it has to be char*. Could you say me how I can convert this const char* into char*?

Thank you.

Comment: Copy it? http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup

Comment: Did you mean I should copy from that page?

Comment: No, I meant you should copy the string using the function described.

Comment: Yup, spot on.I did the same.Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since strtok actually writes to your string, you need to make a writable copy of it to tokenize;

```
char* copy = strdup(myReadonlyString);
...tokenize copy...
free(copy);
```

Comment: A c++ way of making a copy would be `std::vector<char> copy(myReadonlyString, myReadonlyString+strlen(myReadonlyString));`. You can then tokenize `copy->data()`. The compiler will de-allocate the copy automatically whenever it goes out of scope.

Comment: @Manuel, the value you've stored in `copy` isn't null-terminated. Use `strlen(myReadonlyString) + 1` to ensure the input's terminator is included in the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as an array:

```
char tokenedStr[] = "OpenStack:OpenStack1";
```

if not possible, copy it to a char array.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of your non-modifiable string and then use `strtok`.

You can portably use `malloc` and `strcpy` to copy the string.