# Why does the memory not allocate?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc, cpu-word

My assignment is to allow the user to enter any input and print the occurrences of letters and words. We also have to print out how many one letter, two, three, etc.. letter words are in the string.

The word function has an access violation when dealing the array of pointers. It looks like the `malloc()` function didn't properly allocate memory to my array of pointers and I'm not sure I did the coding right.

I actually tried allocating memory to an index of the array, `word[0]`, and that index had memory that was properly allocated, but when I use a loop it never works, when I hover over the array and check each index it says "Bad PTR".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void findLetters(char *ptr);
void findWords(char *point);


int main()
{
    char textStream[100]; //up to 98 characters and '\n\ and '\0'

    printf("enter some text\n");
    if (fgets(textStream, sizeof (textStream), stdin)) //input up to 99 characters
    {
        findLetters(textStream);
        findWords(textStream);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("fgets failed\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void findLetters(char *ptr) //find occurences of all letters
{ /*Works fine*/ }

void findWords(char *point)
{
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int space = 0;
    int c = 0;
    char *word[50];
    char word1[50][100];
    char* delim = "{ } . , ( ) ";

    for (i = 0; i< sizeof(point); i++) //counts # of spaces between words
    {
        if ((point[i] == ' ') || (point[i] == ',') || (point[i] == '.'))
        {
            space++;
        }
    }
    char *words = strtok(point, delim);
    for(;k <= space; k++)
    {
        word[k] = malloc((words+1) * sizeof(*words));
    }

        while (words != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n",words);
            strcpy(words, word[j++]);
            words = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }

    free(words);
}
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: In `findWords`, why do you assume `space` will be `<=49`? Your `word` array of `char` pointers only holds 50 elements, so you should index it `0-49`.

Comment: I'm fairly certain `sizeof(point)` isn't what you think it is. That's the size of a pointer, not the length of your input sequence.

Comment: Not a good idea of having two variables, one being the plural of the other

Comment: Change `sizeof(point)` to `strlen(point)`.

Comment: May we ask why you are allocating space for `word[k]` to begin with instead of just counting them?

Comment: @David C. Rankin I tried using 2D char arrays to store the words to avoid needing dynamic allocation but I still got an access violation, it seems no matter what I try I end up getting one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 while (words != NULL)
 {
      printf("%s\n",words);
      strcpy(words, word[j++]);
      words = strtok(NULL, delim);
 }

free(words);
```

Think what this code is doing; it loops until `words == NULL`, then tries to `free (words)`, which, if the loop has terminated, is `NULL`. So, you're trying to `free` a `NULL` pointer.

BTW. You don't need to free `strtok`'s return value: [Do I need to free the strtok resulting string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904175/do-i-need-to-free-the-strtok-resulting-string)

EDIT: The solution is this:

1. `for (i = 0; i< sizeof(point); i++)` should be `for (i = 0; i< strlen(point); i++)` - `sizeof(char*)` is not the string's length,
   but the size of a char pointer on your system (4 or 8).
2. Replace everything after that `for` loop above with:

   ```
   char *words = strtok(point, delim);
   for (; k <= space && words != NULL; k++)
   {
       if (k >= 50)    //size of the word array
       {
           puts ("Too many words!");
           return;
       }      

       word[k] = malloc(strlen(words) + 1);

       strcpy(word[k], words);
       words = strtok(NULL, delim);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
       free(word[i]);
   ```

That code is from Cool Guy's answer, except he had a bug there - the code was incrementing `k` twice.

Note that this code is pretty pointless as it is, it just allocates some memory, copies some stuff there, and frees that memory without doing anything, but I assume you want to do something else in the `findWords` function after that.

Comment: Fyi, `free(NULL)` is completely legitimate and has standard-defined behavior (effectively a no-op).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yup, just wanted to point that out since it's pointless and against the rules.

Comment: It is not against the rules

Comment: I meant freeing `strtok`'s return string is against the rules, which is what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The memory finally allocates properly and I don't get an access violation so far.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` replaces all delimiters with `'\0'` (= it modifies your input string).

So if you want to build an array containing pointers to all the words in your input array you can simply write the following:

```
void findWords(char *point)
{
    int count = 0;
    char *word[50];
    char* delim = "{ } . , ( ) ";
    char *words = strtok(point, delim);

    count = 0;
    while (words != NULL)
    {
        word[count] = words;
        count++;

        printf("%s\n",words);
        words = strtok(NULL, delim);

        if (count >= 50)   // word is limited to char *word[50] !!!
        {
             printf("too much words!\n");
             break;
        }
    }

    /*
    ** now count contains the number of words and
    ** word[0 .. (count - 1)] contains the words
    */
}
```

There is no need to allocate memory.

Running this little test

```
char test1[] = "hallo test, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50";
char test2[] = "hallo test (2)";

findWords(test1);
findWords(test2);
```

shows the following (break point before leaving function `findWords`):
[image: debugging function findWords]

Within function `findWords` the contents of `word` are correct.

Comment: @CoolGuy: I've posted screenshots and some test code showing that the function works properly. What is your input to function `findWords`?

Comment: Oops! I forgot that `strtok` modifies and adds NUL-terminators.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
for(;k <= space; k++)
{
    word[k] = malloc((words+1) * sizeof(*words));
}

    while (words != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",words);
        strcpy(words, word[j++]);
        words = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

free(words);
```

with

```
for(;k <= space && words != NULL; k++)
{
    //word[k] = malloc((words+1) * sizeof(*words)); //Doesn't do what you think; You need strlen
    word[k] = malloc( strlen(words) + 1); //+1 for the NUL-terminator

    printf("%s\n",words);
    strcpy(word[k], words); //Arguments were mixed up. You want the opposite
    words = strtok(NULL, delim);
}

for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    free(word[i]);       //Free each index as you've allocated each of them not `words`
```

Also,

```
for (i = 0; i< sizeof(point); i++)
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i< strlen(point); i++)
```

or better

```
int len = strlen(point);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

because `sizeof(point)` gives the size of a `char*` which is not want you want. So, use `strlen`.

Comment: I made the changes and I still get an access violation when I try to allocate memory for each index of the array

Comment: @Karlioh , Try adding `if(k>=50){ printf("Too many tokens, bailing out");break; }` just before the `malloc`.